# "It is the god-given given that must be accepted because it cannot be changed." vs a colon

Tags: writing-style, colons

Is the difference purely stylistic, or is there a slight change of meaning in using one form of over the other?

"It is the god-given given that must be accepted because it cannot be changed," as opposed to:
"It is the god-given given that must be accepted: it cannot be changed."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a slight difference in meaning.

*must be accepted because it cannot be changed* means that this is the reason it must be accepted.

*must be accepted: it cannot be changed* is making two related statements: it must be accepted *and* it cannot be changed. But no causal relationship is directly stated, although it might be inferred from the logic. There are probably some other sentences that would have the same form, but the causal relationship would be reversed (i.e. the cause would precede the colon); the relationship comes from the logic, not the sentence structure.